# How to run a Concourse task conditionally?

Tags: concourse, concourse-git-resource

I am modifying a concourse script I inherited.

We have a pipeline that looks like this:

`[1]build - [2]test A - [3]test B - [4]publish - [5]deploy`

Our team worked only with the master branch before but now we are using feature branches.

I made a modification to `build step` to run for every branch - not only master. But I want `publish step` to run **only for the master branch builds**.

How can I make `step 5` to run only when the `step 1` was run *for the master branch*? Is there a way of doing this on Concourse?

Comment: Hello, it is not clear what you are asking. Please add more details.

Comment: @marco.m thanks for your comment. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0):

If the same pipeline builds all the branches, then either you are not using the git resource or you are using a modified git resource that supports multiple branches.

I assume that what you call "steps" 1...5 are Concourse jobs.

I can see two options.

- Option 1. Simple but dirty/misleading.

At the beginning of steps 4 and 5, check for the git branch. If not master, return success immediately. The pipeline will stay green and the publish and deploy jobs will look like they have ran, while actually they did nothing.

- Option 2. Slightly more complicated but the proper way.

Use two pipelines. One pipeline for all branches except master. This pipeline will contain only steps 1 ... 3. The second pipeline will track the master branch and have all the steps 1 ... 5.

The question now is how to manage these 2 pipelines in a DRY fashion (no code duplication, no possibility for the pipelines to drift away one from the other)?

The answer is to use a YAML merge tool like https://github.com/geofffranks/spruce. The README mentions BOSH but it is a completely generic YAML merge tool.

The last part is how to stay DRY and at the same time specify different branches. This can be obtained with https://concourse-ci.org/setting-pipelines.html#pipeline-vars.